# My code throws an error about a NoneType, but it should be defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've tried to redefine the location, but it won't stop throwing a NoneType error.

I've also tried to define the direction as well in the class, but to no avail. I've also tried to remove the declaring off the location in the Head **init** function, with no change.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 55, in <module>
    head.draw()
  File "main.py", line 39, in draw
    start_point = (self.location[0] + paddingSize, self.location[0] + paddingSize)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```py
import pygame

size = 24
paddingSize = 1
displaySize = 960

def add(a, b):
    a = list(a)
    for xi in range(len(a)):
        a[xi] += b[xi]


class SnakePart:
    location = (0, 0)  # x, y
    direction = (0, 0)

    def __init__(self, next_part, direction):
        self.direction = direction
        self.location = next_part.location
        if direction[0]:  # up
            self.location[0] += 1
        elif not direction[0]:  # down
            self.location[0] -= 1
        elif direction[1]:  # right
            self.location[0] += 1
        elif not direction[1]:  # left
            self.location[0] -= 1


class Head(SnakePart):
    def __init__(self, start_pos, direction):
        self.location = start_pos
        self.direction = direction

    def move(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def draw(self):
        start_point = (self.location[0] + paddingSize, self.location[0] + paddingSize)
        end_point = (start_point[0] + paddingSize + sizeOfSquare, start_point[1] + paddingSize + sizeOfSquare)
        self.location = add(self.location, self.direction)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (52, 60, 107), pygame.Rect(start_point, end_point))


pygame.display.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(displaySize, displaySize))
surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
sizeOfSquare = (displaySize/size)-paddingSize*2
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.key.set_repeat(100)
head = Head((0, 0), (-1, 0))
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    head.draw()
```

Comment: `add()` never returns a value, and `paddingSize` is never defined on the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add() doesn't return a value, so location becomes None, leading to your Exception.